# Using profiles to control which Maven modules are built

Tags: maven, profiles

I have the following XML in my maven POM.xml:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>default</id>
     <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        <property>
           <name>default</name>
           <value>!disabled</value>
        </property>
     </activation>
     <modules>
        <module>m1</module>
        <module>m2</module>
        <module>m3</module>
     </modules>
  </profile>
  <profile>
     <id>x</id>
     <modules>
        <module>m1</module>
     </modules>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

1. When I run `mvn install`, I want it to build m1, m2 and m3 projects.
2. When I run `mvn install -Px`, I want it to **only** build m1.

My current problem is that with the code above, option 2 builds all m1, m2 and m3.

Comment: Why do you have the activation properties set for the default profile? You say that you want it to run by default but also if that property does not have the value "disabled". Remove the whole property part from first profile.

Comment: I've done that but does not help. The problem now is that no modules are built when 'mvn install' is run.

Comment: I tested the very same profiles without the `property` part and it works just as you want. Try with these commands: `mvn help:active-profiles` and `mvn -Px help:active-profiles`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Found the solution guys, define 'x' profile first and the 'default' and it works fine (insane Maven!!). Here's the final result:

```
   <profiles>
      <!-- DO NOT CHANGE THE *ORDER* IN WHICH THESE PROFILES ARE DEFINED! -->
      <profile>
         <id>x</id>
         <modules>
            <module>m1</module>
         </modules>
      </profile>
      <profile>
         <id>default</id>
         <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <modules>
            <module>m1</module>
            <module>m2</module>
            <module>m3</module>
         </modules>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
```

Comment: What version of maven are you using? That should not make any difference.

Comment: Ordering does not make sense here.. i was looking for something similar.. I can call any profile and  when i want to build all modules i just do not give the profile ,so modules n sequence are executed

Comment: I agree. I was having the same issue but the resolution turned out to be that when I use profiles, I have to explicitly remove my modules from the <project> root and declare them in the <profiles> (thus creating a default profile). 
I tried switching the order to validate this answer and it did not change anything here. @Galder Zamarreño what maven version were you using? I want to try and reproduce to ensure it's not a maven bug. Mine was 3.5.0.

Comment: what if there is a common module that should be built before all the modules?

Comment: It is worth to mention to remove any `<modules>` declaration in the pom.xml and only use the ones inside the `<profiles>`.

Comment: @sahlouls you are my hero. it was worth mentioning

Comment: If you remove `<modules>` from the root of pom.xml, then you should include it in the profile, which has all the modules, in the `mvn install` command. Like, before: `mvn clean install -Pneeded-profile1,needed-profile2`, after: `mvn clean install -Pprofile-where-modules-declared,needed-profile1,needed-profile2`

Answer (score 6):

You can disable maven profiles that have `runByDefault` set to true from the command line like so:

`mvn install -P !default`

Note, this requires Maven version 2.0.10.

Comment: That'd be great but what happens is that I cannot change the actual maven commands. For IDEs, to figure out which projects to import into the workspace, they use something like 'mvn install', and the 2nd command is what one cloud provider runs for me, I cannot change that either.

Comment: IOW, I want a way to achieve this only modifying the pom.xml.

Answer (score -15):

Just add a space after -P the sintax of the command is

```
mvn install -P x
```

And not like you are using

```
mvn install -Px
```

Take a look at [Maven - Introduction to profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)