# how to disable rpm-maven-plugin on sub modules

Tags: maven, rpm-maven-plugin

I have a maven project that has submodules:

```
/pom.xml
/child1/pom.xml
/child2.pom.xml
```

When I do a "maven package", it creates a /target/foo.jar. Good.

When I do a "maven rpm:rpm", my build fails because when it goes to build one of the childs, it says:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-3:attached-rpm (default-cli)
on project child1: Source location target/foo.jar does not exist
```

I don't want the child projects to do an rpm. I only want the parent to rpm its artifact.

The [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/usage.html) says:

```
If this goal is run on a project with modules, 
it will run the "rpm:rpm" goal on each module, rather than packaging 
the modules into a single RPM.
```

Is there a way to get around this?
I cannot have the rpm be created when doing a "mvn package", since it does not work on a mac, which is what most people develop on here: the rpm should only be created when doing a "mvn rpm:rpm", or similar command.

Here is the parent pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <name>analytics-reporting</name>
    <group>rpm</group>
    <targetVendor>amazon</targetVendor>
    <targetOS>Linux</targetOS>
    <filemode>644</filemode>
    <username>root</username>
    <groupname>root</groupname>
    <copyright>LGPL</copyright>
    <version>${rpm.version}</version>
    <release>${rpm.release}</release>
    <mappings>
      <mapping>
        <directory>/opt/inin</directory>
        <sources>
          <source>
            <location>target/analytics-reporting-engine.jar</location>
          </source>
        </sources>
      </mapping>
    </mappings>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is the child:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>none</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14210506/1089062. Put that in your child poms.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it didn't work.  It makes perfect sense to me that it should work, but it didn't, and I don't understand why.  I'll update my original question with the parent pom and child pom.

Comment: I used a solution based on maven profiles, to exclude the modules on a specific profile,  as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13383092/379173

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property for that.
https://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/rpm-mojo.html#disabled

```
<rpm.disabled>true</rpm.disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the plugin's executions you need to specify not to inherit the plugin, like so:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <id>attach-rpm</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>attached-rpm</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```