# Skipping maven shade plugin in a spring-boot project based on maven profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, java-8

I want to skip the execution of maven-shade-plugin when a certain maven profile is activated on a spring-boot project. As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13383092/785523) I have made my `pom.xml` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.van.saasinfra</groupId>
    <artifactId>saas-controller</artifactId>
    <version>0.001-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>saas-controller</name>
    <description>SaaS Controller</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev-local</id>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mvn.shade.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>saas-controller-shade</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources"/>
                                <exec executable="protoc">
                                    <arg value="--java_out=${project.build.directory}/generated-sources"/>
                                    <arg value="--proto_path=${project.basedir}/src/main/proto"/>
                                    <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/com/van/saasinfra/saascontroller/saas-controller.proto"/>
                                    <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/com/van/saasinfra/saascontroller/billing-controller.proto"/>
                                    <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/com/van/saasinfra/saascontroller/node-topology.proto"/>
                                    <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/com/van/saasinfra/saascontroller/availability.proto"/>
                                    <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/com/van/saasinfra/saascontroller/dynamodb-config.proto"/>
                                    <arg value="${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/com/van/saasinfra/saascontroller/tenant-migration.proto"/>
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</sourceRoot>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But even when doing `maven clean install -Pdev-local` I am seeing shade step is still getting executed.

Can some suggest how to stop the execution of shade when a certain profile is enabled on a spring boot project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/index.html) that also allows you to repackage your application. Its `repackage` goal automatically activates during the `package` phase, so you don't even need to define an execution.

Back to your question, if you want to skip execution of a certain plugin, many plugins have a `skip` property that you can set. The Spring Boot Maven Plugin has one. You can set it in the XML configuration, but there's also a *user property* for it. As a result, your *dev-local* profile could look like this:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>dev-local</id>
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

But you could even skip the profile completely and invoke Maven with `-Dspring-boot.repackage.skip=true`.

The [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) has no such property documented, so that could be a reason for using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin over the Maven Shade Plugin.

Finally, for building applications, you typically don't need `mvn clean install`, but `mvn verify` would be enough. Saves you a few seconds in execution and saves a lot of disk space in the long run since it doesn't copy built artifacts to your local Maven repo (`~/.m2/repository` or `%userprofile%\.m2\repository`).

Comment: I claim that no commandline argument should effect the resulting artifact. Hence, to me it makes sense that the maven-shade-plugin has no skip parameter.

Comment: Would that include activating or deactivating profiles?

Comment: Yes. And this is where it gets tricky. For that reason most Maven Developers avoid profiles, they've become too powerful. Valid usage of profiles: integration-tests (might take too long), codecoverage (activate it on the buildserver). Invalid (worst) usage: dev/test/prod. These imply embedded environment configuration.